# running neo4j in docker: "NO MODE SPECIFIED!"

Tags: python, django, docker, neo4j, docker-compose

I added neo4j to my docker-compose.yml file.
It succesfully created, but while docker-compose up command it gives me this two error messages for neo4j:

```
   NO MODE SPECIFIED! 
   env variables are populated(think that is not important)
```

and excites with

```
  neo4j exited with code 1
```

Also, I am adding MODE to environments, but how I see didn't help.
that is how my docker-compose.yml looks like:

```
   neo4j:
 image: neo4j:4.0.5
 hostname: neo4j
 container_name: neo4j
 ports:
   - "7474:7474"
   - "7687:7687"
 volumes:
   - ./data:/data
 environment:
   - NEO4J_dbms_mode=CORE
```

Comment: Is your YAML formatted correctly? And you might want to add an NEO4J_AUTH env variable for username/password.

Comment: @MichaelHunger yes, it is correct because other services are working. Yes I have this variable, just didn't write it here

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  neo4j:
    image: neo4j:4.0.5
    hostname: neo4j
    container_name: neo4j
    ports:
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7687:7687"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
    environment:
      NEO4J_AUTH: neo4j/secret
```

```
docker-compose up
Starting neo4j ... 
Starting neo4j ... done
Attaching to neo4j
neo4j    | Warning: Folder mounted to "/data" is not writable from inside container. Changing folder owner to neo4j.
neo4j    | Changed password for user 'neo4j'.
neo4j    | Directories in use:
neo4j    |   home:         /var/lib/neo4j
neo4j    |   config:       /var/lib/neo4j/conf
neo4j    |   logs:         /logs
neo4j    |   plugins:      /var/lib/neo4j/plugins
neo4j    |   import:       /var/lib/neo4j/import
neo4j    |   data:         /var/lib/neo4j/data
neo4j    |   certificates: /var/lib/neo4j/certificates
neo4j    |   run:          /var/lib/neo4j/run
neo4j    | Starting Neo4j.
neo4j    | 2020-06-15 07:22:27.505+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 4.0.5 ========
neo4j    | 2020-06-15 07:22:27.510+0000 INFO  Starting...
neo4j    | 2020-06-15 07:22:30.673+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on 0.0.0.0:7687.
neo4j    | 2020-06-15 07:22:30.673+0000 INFO  Started.
neo4j    | 2020-06-15 07:22:31.382+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
```

Answer (score 0):

There were no problems with docker-compose.yml file. I just pulled neo4j again and restarted docker. It solved the problem.